# NSArray, appendString, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I just started with Swift and was trying to modify some code but i do not understand the error. I hope someone can shed light on my problem, so here it is.

Qn1.

```
var test: NSArray = [String]()
test[0].appendString("abc") //fatal error: Array index out of range
```

To resolve this, i had to initialise the array with test = [""] but i was under the assumption that the line var test: NSArray = String would have initialise it. Is what i am doing right ?

Qn2.

```
var test: NSArray = [String]()
test = [["xxx", "zzz", "hhh"],["aaa", "qwe", "hyh"]]
test[0].appendString("abc") //[Swift._NSContiguousString appendString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I would like to add another string into the array but this error pops up. I am unclear as to why it is behaving in this manner.

Comment: A standard string is immutable -- you can't append to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qn1. `test` is in fact initialized, but it's empty so test[0] is out of range since there are no elements.

Qn2. `appendString` is an [`NSMutableString` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString:), but test[0] in this case is an array. To add "abc" to your array, use `append`

```
test[0].append("abc")
```

or `+=`

```
test[0] += ["abc"]
```

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Yes, test[0] += ["abc"]. Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus No, it's test[0]. The OP is trying to append to test[0] not test.

Comment: I didn't notice it was an array inside another array

Answer (score 1):

If you're just appending strings to arrays:

```
// Q1
var test = [String]()
test.append("abc")
// Q2
var test = [[String]]()
test = [["xxx", "zzz", "hhh"],["aaa", "qwe", "hyh"]]
test[0].append("abc)
```

Also unless there are some particular reasons to be using `NSArray`, you are best off sticking to native swift arrays.